# How to set cookie from express js

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am using express.js as my api faremwork.trying to set browser cookie from expressjs with response.cookie but it is not saving any cookie on my browser.
No Error in console

Already tried httpOnly false/true,secure false/true

```
res.cookie('nodeSessID', req.sessionID, {maxAge: 24*60*60*1000,httpOnly:false,secure:false,domain:'cz-tuts.com',path:'/'}).json({status:1,message:"success"});


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/*',session({
    secret: 'ThisisTestSecretForCookie',
    // create new redis store.
    name: 'nodeSessID',
    store: new redisStore({host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true,
    cookie: { secure: false,domain:'cz-tuts.com',httpOnly:false,path: '/',maxAge:360000 },
}));
```

cookie should saved in browser

Comment: Can you format above code such that it is readable?

Comment: If browser request is coming from separate domain, it is possible that you are facing CORS issues.

Comment: Hi Sanjeev thanks fro reply but both are from same domain.

Comment: Hi @vikas, is this for domain cz-tuts.com?